# Firefox refresh button changes the src of the iFrame back to original as expected however the iFrame is still showing content from last session

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-browser

Started with
`<iframe src="blank.html" id="theIdOfTheIframe"></iframe>` which is inside a regular html file.

Later, as a result of the user's interaction with the page `someothercontent.html` is displayed in the iFrame by changing its `src` via script.

At this moment if the refresh button of the Firefox browser is hit, the displayed content of the iFrame won't revert back to `blank.html`. It will still be showing `someothercontent.html` while the console says the `src` has actually reverted and now is `blank.html`.

However if we hit ENTER on the keyboard after clicking the address bar (which is another way to refresh the page) the desired result is achieved and the iFrame is actually blank again.

Trying to make that refresh button do what it is supposed to do, I have tried `contentWindow.location.reload(true);` to force something like a "hard refresh" on the iFrame but that changes nothing and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Note: No such problem on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked.

```
const iFrameScriptAccess = document.getElementById('theIdOfTheIframe');
window.addEventListener("load",function() { // Since this will fire every time the refresh button is clicked or just F5.
  let whatTheFileNameInFrameSrcIs = iFrameScriptAccess.src.substring(iFrameScriptAccess.src.length - 10, iFrameScriptAccess.src.length-5); // Get the name of the html file without folder name and file extension.
  if (whatTheFileNameInFrameSrcIs == "blank") { // This is the moment when Firefox is giving a false positive to you and you want to make it actually show the blank.html file and not something else.
    setTimeout( function ()  {   iFrameScriptAccess.src="whateverfolder/blank.html"  },100); // Force empty! And finally things are as they are supposed to be.
  }
 });
```